# Too many positional arguments 0 expected but 1 found

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

```
CollectionReference userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await userRef.doc(updateUser.uid).get();
var userModel = UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data());
context.read(userInformation).state = userModel;
```

This is my code as shown above.
I'm getting this error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected but 1 found for the line of code context.read(userInformation).state = userModel

I have the variable userInformation declared as follows:

```
final userInformation = StateProvider((ref) => UserModel());
```

I have already tried importing the provider package but still this error keeps on showing. Please suggest what should I change. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this.

`context.read<userInformation>().state = userModel;`

Comment: Hey, I tried this. Still not working. It says the name userInformation isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide the code for the provider class.